# C++ modify array outside of main and print new numbers from main along with the number of results?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

new to C++ and learning about arrays and functions.

I need to use 2 functions outside of function main. The first to read numbers inputted by the user and store them in an array. The user enters positive numbers followed by a negative number to signify the end of the list. The second to find any negative numbers and return them to main. Once in main, I need to print those negative numbers along with how many there are.

I have the first part down, I'm just trying to figure out how to accomplish the second part. The second part is a bit of a mess so I apologize in advance (I've tried a few different things). A side note: I realize that index isn't a great variable name, but just go with it.

Any help is super appreciated, thank you!

Here is some of the code I have down.

```
#include <iostream> //for cin and cout

using namespace std;

const int max_size = 20;    //maximum size of array

//function prototypes
void read_list(int[], int&);
int find_negative(int[], int);

int main()
{
    //array of positive integers with max size specified
    int list[max_size];
    
    //variable for number of positive integers in the array
    int number_of_integers;

    //variable for counter
    int index;

    //read inputted integers
    read_list(list, number_of_integers);

    //find any negative numbers via a function then display result in main.
    find_negative(list, number_of_integers);

    //print any negative numbers        
    for (index=0; index < number_of_integers; index++)
    {
        cout << list[index-1] << " ";
    }

    return 0; 
}

void read_list(int list[], int& length)
{
    //variables for loop and entered numbers
    int number;
    int index = 0;

    //prompt the user to enter numbers
    cout << "To get started, please enter a number of positive "
         << "integers, each separated by a blank space.\n"
         << "Mark the end of the list with a negative number: ";
    
    //read the first number
    cin >> number;

    //check whether entered number is positive or negative
    //and that the size of the array is not exceeded
    while (number>=0 && index < max_size)
    {
        //store the entered integer in the array
        list[index] = number;
        
        //increment the index
        index++;

        //read the next integer
        cin >> number;
    }
    //length is the number of positive integers in the array
    length = index;
}

int find_negative(int list[], int length)
{
    int index; //counter
  
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
       while (index < 0)
        {
            list[index] = index - 1;
        }
    }
    return list[index];
}
```

Comment: *The second to find any negative numbers and return them to main.* -- But the first part mentions that no number is negative that is being inputted until the final number.  So what negative numbers are you searching for?

Comment: The loop `while (index < 0)` doesn't modify `index`, and so will be infinite.

Comment: Also `return list[index];`will be used when the index is out of bounds.